# If you're using stdout-stdin already, could you somehow use a higher file descriptor?

Tags: bash, openssl

Can the following be done without creating a temp.pem?

```
openssl pkcs12 -passin pass:notasecret -in $DATASTORE_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE -nocerts -nodes -out temp.pem
cat myfile | openssl sha -sha256 -sign temp.pem | cat
```

Was thinking of using -sign /dev/stdin but then I need a -in myfile parameter that is not available.

Comment: If you're using stdout-stdin already, could you somehow use a higher file descriptor?

Comment: I assume you wanted me to edit the title :)

Comment: No, I was actually asking. If the `stdout` (`&1`) of the first invocation of `openssl` already being used, you might be able to somehow make it write to a different file descriptor (`&3` or something), then make the second invocation of `openssl` get the file from the other descriptor.

Comment: …or what @DavidFoerster said. That works better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common way would be to use a FIFO and make the shell manage it:

```
cat myfile | openssl sha -sha256 -sign <(openssl pkcs12 -passin pass:notasecret -in $DATASTORE_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE -nocerts -nodes) | cat
```